# EGM96 5' geoid model .tif file

Tags: wgs84, ellipsoid, geoid, egm96

Where can I find a .tif file of the EGM96 geoid height above the WGS84 ellipsoid with 5' resolution ?

I am working on converting vertical datum on different kind of files from WGS84 to EGM96 and surch a file would be helpful.
Agisoft Metashape provides a [15' resolution one](https://www.agisoft.com/downloads/geoids/), but I am looking for the 5' one.

Comment: But the master accuracy is 1 meter, so EGM96 must have 2.5'x2.5' somewhere. See https://epsg.org/crs_5773/EGM96-height.html?sessionkey=hkady0sgdl vs https://epsg.org/crs_3855/EGM2008-height.html?sessionkey=g4m41pk5zg the EGM2008 has 2 geoids, 1st is 1 meter accuracy and is 2.5'x2.5' and second is 0.5 meter and is 1'x1'.